# Boiler Gauge Readings

Tags: boiler

Trying to understand this gauge and ensure everything is working as intended.
I know the top part is the temperature of the water I am assuming at the boiler. Again PSI of the water pressure, but what is the red arrow all the way at the bottom what is that telling me?

Also if can tell me are these ok numbers or how do I find out if they are ok.

Thank you

[image: Gauge]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it shows a temperature of 170f which may be ok if that is what you want delivered.

As for pressure it shows 15psi, this could be incoming pressure or the pressure in a closed system.

The red arrow or indicator is most likely showing the max pressure recommended.

You should get the manual for your boiler and check the functions and settings **before** trying to change anything.